# How to get Sphinx working in PyCharm with Python 3.5

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, virtualenv, python-sphinx, docutils

This is my first time using Sphinx in PyCharm 5.0 with Python 3.5.

When I run `sphinx task` in PyCharm I get the following error:

```
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 5.0\helpers\docutils\__init__.py", line 63, in <module>
    class ApplicationError(StandardError): pass
NameError: name 'StandardError' is not defined
```

On [this page](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.text.docutils.user/7373) I discovered that in Python 3.x `StandardError` is now replaced with `Exception`. However, when I try to edit the `__init__.py` file PyCharm prevents me from saving it.

I also noticed that `__init__.py` is based off of docutils version 0.8. This is not intuitive since I installed docutils version 0.12 in my virtualenv. Meaning that version 0.12 is being ignored.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Update: PyCharm 5.0.2 fixes this, and Sphinx run configurations work under Python 3*

Unfortunately the Python code shipped in PyCharm pre-5.0.2 helpers is not Python 3 compatible. The PyCharm issue tracker has a ticket. I once gave a crack at fixing all the small boo-boos, but then ran into some bigger ones.

So instead, just make a Run Configuration that calls:

- `Script (on Mac): /Users/paul/projects/jetbrains/env35/bin/sphinx-build`
- `Script parameters: -b html -d _build/doctrees . _build/html`

...and set the working directory to the place you want the `_build` directory.

---

**Edit:** Added a link for how to create and edit run/debug configurations in pycharm and a screenshot for windows. Script location is 'Scripts' as opposed to 'bin'.

[Creating and Editing Run/Debug Configurations in PyCharm 5.0](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html)

PyCharm 5.0 Screenshot (on Windows)
[image: PyCharm 5.0 Screenshot (on Windows)]